# Incrementar el %5 a un valor en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, update

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
db.proyectos.update(
    {"Días de Desviación":{$gte:5}},
    { $set: { "Costo":{$sum:{ $multiply: [ "$Costo", .05 ] } } }},
    { multi: true }
)
```

Lo que necesito es ***incrementar el Costo*** ya establecido un *%5*, pero me arroja un error (todo lo tengo que hacer desde el *shell*).

El error que me genera es el siguiente:

> ```
> WriteResult({
>   "nMatched" : 0,
>   "nUpserted" : 0,
>   "nModified" : 0,
>   "writeError" : {
>     "code" : 52,
>     "errmsg" :
>  "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$sum' in 'Costo.$sum' is not valid for storage."
>   }
> })
> ```

Comment: Como lo indica el error, los nombres de las variables no deberían tener el signo pesos (`$`). En vez de `$gte`, `$set`, `$sum`, `$multiply` y `$Costo`, deberían ser `gte`, `set`, `multiply` y `Costo`.

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que especifica aqui es necesario: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Comment: @Flicker Para que al usuario que quieras responder le llegue en la bandeja de entrada, hay que escribir el signo `@` seguido del nombre de usuario, en este caso era yo. A pesar de esto me enteré porque volví a entrar por casualidad a la pregunta. Respondiendo al comentario, voy entendiendo que entonces el signo pesos es necesario, pero según indica el error, quizás debas hacer una variable que repita su valor pero sin el signo pesos, ya que puede ser válido usar ese signo pero no en el _storage_.

Comment: @ArtEze Gracias

Comment: @Flicker De nada. Si llegas a solucionarlo puedes publicar una respuesta a tu pregunta en la sección de abajo explicando los detalles y recién luego de dos días poder marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Para incrementar en un porcentaje un campo numérico en MongoDB, puedes usar el operador [`$mul`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/) de esta forma:

```
db.proyectos.update(
    {"Días de Desviación":{$gte:5}},
    { $mul: { Costo: 1.05 } },
    { multi: true }
)
```